# Kubernetes Nginx ingress timeout for two requests only

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

In our k8s ingress configuration we set timeout to 10min and its applying to all requests. Is it possible to configure timeout only to two requests like `/my-service/v1/processfile` and `/my-service/v1/cachewarmup`.

Currently our configuration is as follows:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '600'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-service-dev1.eus1-devqa.geo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service-svc
          servicePort: 8080
```

Can anyone please help me to configure nginx ingress timeout for two requests only to 10min and all other requests default to 1min.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a separate `Ingress` resource that contains only those two paths, since Ingress matches by most specific pattern:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '60'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '60'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '60'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-service-dev1.eus1-devqa.geo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service-svc
          servicePort: 8080
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service-600
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '600'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-service-dev1.eus1-devqa.geo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my-service/v1/processfile
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service-svc
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /my-service/v1/cachewarmup
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service-svc
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: hi @mdaniel Thanks a lot... its working fine..

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with keycloak and see  [error] 17297#17297: *91945328 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.233.74.64, server: keycloak.dev.testlab.tech, request: "GET /auth/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://10.244.98.160:8443/auth/". After creating separate "keycloak.dev.testlab.tech", same issue remains.

Comment: @Sanjeev please don't squat on other people's questions; asking questions is free, and there is no way you can provide the amount of detail required to help you in the comment field. Good luck

Comment: @mdaniel, my query was based on same original issue, except the application is keycloak. Fyi comment section is for **hints** not for detailing out. By the way, I have the solution to my issue. I am on bare metal k8 cluster where I was trying with N/W policy=true. I set it false for the time being & I cleared the browser cache too (this can also the cause of the issue)